# HTML background with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am clueless about the background of http://startupgiraffe.com/

I have searched a lot about creating background with shapes and css but of no use. Can some one please guide me towards creating a background like http://startupgiraffe.com/.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the source code op startupgiraffe; there are multiple "background" parts:

```
<section id="background-wrapper" class="full-wrapper">

  <section id="first-background">
    <div id="scroll-trigger"></div>
  </section>

  <section id="second-background">
  </section>

  <section id="third-background">
  </section>

  ----

</section>
```

They have used a lot of javascripting to dynamically switch between the background sections resulting in a concatenated background.

If you would like to replicate this behavior or learn more details about it, I suggest you start looking at the source code of the html, css and javascript. You could also use your browsers analysis tools (firebug, chrome's console) to find out more of the website's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First step is fire up Chrome's dev tools (or whatever you like – Chrome is good), go to Network, and click images at the bottom:

[image: Dev Tools]

That lets you see what's going on.

In short though, absolute positioning in CSS + lots of images.